# Fixing texture brush

Tags: texturing, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I'm trying to use a texture brush that i've added, the source "skin" brush is a 528 by 528 image.
When I use my brush with dyntopo resolution set 200, this is the result. Obviously this is incorrect.  what settings to do I need to change to remedy this?
[image]

Comment: The 200 is a too big value, try with 3-5.

Comment: I'll give that a shot thanks response!